# Why is the methyl chloride and sodium hydroxide reaction irreversible?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is the reaction of methyl chloride and sodium hydroxide (aq) irreversible simply due to the relative stability of sodium hydroxide and sodium chloride? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Which reaction and under what conditions?

Comment: Think about what the product of the reaction is going to be, assuming that the $\ce NaOH$ is aq (as stated) and dilute.